# Передача данных через сокеты

Tags: c#, сокет

Здравствуй ХешКод, вопрос в таком, у меня есть список

- http://yandex.ru
- http://google.ru
- http://mail.ru

Вот мне надо передать это с сервера в клиент, и поместить в listBox.. но я не знаю как это сделать? У меня вариант только один:

```
string[] text = new string[2];
text[0] = "http://yandex.ru";
text[1] = "http://google.ru";
text[2] = "http://mail.ru";

for(int i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
   byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text[1]);
}
```

И тут отправка идёт, но мне надо узнать как скомпоновать данные чтобы их отправить, и потом можно было разделить и внести в listBox(каждый в новой строке)

Answer (score 2):

В конкретном случае ничего компоновать не нужно, пересылаются нуль-терминированные строки. Сервер отправляет эти строки одну за другой, а клиент забирает их из сокета по очереди. Чтобы не писать свои велосипеды, можно читать штатным классом `StreamReader`.